# Best way to check if SPListItem have been publish, on an ItemUpdate EventReceiver

Tags: publishing, splistitem, event-receivers

I have an EventReceiver associated to DocLib template id, triggered at every ItemUpdate. 
Everytime an SPListItem is publish I want to execute my code.

(Required check out and Content approval are turned off)

So, is the type ItemUpdated the best one in this case? What the best way to check if item was publish?

spregards

Comment: Why not check properties.ListItem.Level == SPFileLevel.Published?

Comment: It won't work for the case when file is checked out. Level in this case will show CheckedOut state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ItemUpdated check

```
properties.ListItem.File.MinorVersion == 0
```

Comment: This is Sharepoint :D

Comment: @per - am I right in assuming this isn't a way to tell whether the event was fired because it has been published? I need a way of testing the beforeproperties against the afterproperties to monitor changes to whether the document is published or not (i.e. need an event to fire on publishing) but cannot find the appropriate field name.

Comment: I'd extend this a bit. If file is checked out by current user and this user tries to check using this one - it will be needed compare with 1. For other users - check with 0 will work just fine.